# Gosublime indent not working (might be there is an issue with gofmt in gosublime)

Tags: sublimetext3, indentation, gofmt, gosublime

I have pasted two images here

Here you can see proper indentation in **Gedit** text editor

[image: Proper Indentation in Gedit]

Now, in **Sublime3** it is not proper

[image: sublime indentation]

I'm using **GoSublime** and my settings are:

```
{
    "env": {
        "GOROOT": "/usr/local/go",
        "GOPATH":"$HOME/go-work"
    }
}
```

How to ident go code properly in sublime text editor?

Comment: sounds like you want to use a monospace / fixed-width font

Comment: oh, is it not working with other fonts? Yes, I've read somewhere this issue. Btw I'm using `ubuntu` font